# Add space (like letter spacing) after some amount of characters

Tags: css

Given an Input field

```
<input type="text" />
```

Type in somer Numbers 000000000000

Now the desired result is: 000 000 000 000

There is no way to do this right now in `CSS` is there?

Comment: No, not in css, but it's simple in JS or PHP

Comment: No, there isn't. You'll need some RegEx and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No, not in css, but it's simple in JS or PHP [Justinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346234/justinas)
- No, there isn't. You'll need some RegEx and JS. [BenM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367401/benm)
- With pure CSS it is not possible. [Rahul Tripathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501794/rahul-tripathi)
- You cannot do it in CSS. [Wiglaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736348/wiglaf)

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS it is not possible. However if you are using PHP or Javascript then you can have it. Like for example in PHP you can try like this:

```
<?php

$str = "000000000000";
echo chunk_split($str, 3, ' ');
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/UoODDY)**

**On a side note:**

You can also check about [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) which is used to give space after every character in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for helping Rahul. I know I could also check for word-spacing it's just not what I want/need :)

Comment: @caramba:- Until and unless you find any hack(*which I am not sure is there*), I dont think you can achieve that via CSS alone :)

Comment: I also wasn't sure, that's why I asked here. In my eyes this should be possible at some stage cause it's a styling only thing...